# Expose port in docker-compose or configure second letsencrypt certificate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, lets-encrypt

I'm running a selfhosted gitlab docker instance, but I'm facing some problems configuring the registry as I do get the error

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://example.com:4567/v2/: dial tcp <IP>:4567: connect: connection refused
```

for doing `docker login example.com:4567`.

1. So it seems that I have to expose the port `4567` somehow.
2. An (better) alternative would be to configure a second domain for the registry - like `registry.example.com`. As you can see below I'm using letsencrypt certificates for my gitlab instance. But how do I get a second certificate for the registry?

---

This is how my docker-compose looks like - I'm using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` for my reverse proxy.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
gitlab:
  image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:11.9.0-ce.0
  container_name: gitlab
  networks:
    - reverse-proxy
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - '50022:22'
  volumes:
    - /opt/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
    - /opt/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
    - /opt/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
    - /opt/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - /opt/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: example.com
    VIRTUAL_PROTO: https
    VIRTUAL_PORT: 443
    LETSENCRYPT_HOST: example.com
    LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: certs@example.com
```

**gitlab.rb**

```
external_url 'https://example.com'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = '/etc/nginx/certs/example.com/fullchain.pem'
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = '/etc/nginx/certs/example.com/key.pem'
gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800
gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = '/backups'
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true

registry_external_url 'https://example.com:4567'
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/nginx/certs/example.com/fullchain.pem"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/nginx/certs/example.com/key.pem"
```

For the second alternative it would look like:

```
registry_external_url 'https://registry.example.com'
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/nginx/certs/registry.example.com/fullchain.pem"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/nginx/certs/registry.example.com/key.pem"
```

But how do I set this up in my docker-compose?

---

*Update*

Im configuring nginx just via jwilder package, without changing anyhting. So this part of my docker-compose.yml file just looks like this:

```
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /opt/nginx-proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - /opt/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-letsencrypt
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - /opt/nginx-proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /opt/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
    environment:
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: "nginx-proxy"
```

Comment: I understand that you have a domain `example.com` configured to point on your machine hosting Gitlab in Docker and a reverse proxy with nginx, is that correct? If so, can you upload the related nginx config?

Comment: @PierreB. I'm using the jwilder package which configures nginx. I don't have to change anything...

Comment: What's your `jwilder/nginx-proxy` config then? (which host do you configure?) it may be an issue with the proxy config which does not expose the port properly

Comment: @PierreB. Just updated the post to show how I'm running nginx proxy. I don't configure anything else. Just running the docker-compose on my ubuntu server and that's it. Everything is working beside the registry stuff...

Comment: Thanks for the details, I tried to provide some leads in my answer

Answer (score 3):

**TL; DR:**

> So it seems that I have to expose the port 4567 somehow.

Yes, however [`jwilder/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) does not support more than one port per virtual host and port `443` is already exposed. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/pull/1157) for that feature but it has not been merged yet. You'll need to expose this port another way (see below)

---

You are using [`jwilder/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) as reverse proxy to access a Gitlab instance in a container but with your current configuration onlyport `443` is exposed:

```
environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: example.com
    VIRTUAL_PROTO: https
    VIRTUAL_PORT: 443
```

All other Gitlab services (including the registry on port `4567`) are not proxied and therefore not reachable through `example.com`.

Unfortunately it **is not possible *yet*** to expose multiple port on a single hostname with `jwilder/nginx-proxy`. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/pull/1157) open for that use case but it had not been merged yet (you are not the only one with this kind of issue).

> An (better) alternative would be to configure a second domain for the registry

This won't work if you keep using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` as even if you changed `registry_external_url`, you'll still be stuck with the port issue, and you cannot allocate the same port to two different services.

What you can do:

- vote and comment for mentioned PR to be merged :)
- try to build the Docker image from mentionned [pull request's fork](https://github.com/frederikbosch/nginx-proxy/tree/specific-port) and configure your compose with something like `VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com:443,example.com:4567`
- configure a reverse proxy manually fort port 4567 - you may wind-up a plain `nginx` container in addition with your current configuration which would specifically do this, or re-configure your entire proxying scheme without using *jwilder* images
- update your configuration to expose example.com:4567 instead of example.com:443 but you'll lose HTTPS access. (though it's probably not what you are looking for)

I am aware this does not provide a finite solution but I hope it helps.